# Airflow - Disable heartbeat logs

Tags: python, airflow

My logs are getting completely flooded with useless messages for every heartbeat.

```
[2019-11-27 21:32:47,890] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:32:47,889] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.02 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.983326 s
[2019-11-27 21:32:52,921] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:32:52,921] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.02 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.984673 s
[2019-11-27 21:32:57,949] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:32:57,949] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.01 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.985953 s
[2019-11-27 21:33:02,980] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:33:02,980] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.02 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.984688 s
[2019-11-27 21:33:08,008] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:33:08,008] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.01 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.987069 s
[2019-11-27 21:33:13,041] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:33:13,041] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.02 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.984275 s
[2019-11-27 21:33:18,072] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:33:18,071] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.01 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.986545 s
[2019-11-27 21:33:23,101] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:33:23,100] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.02 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.984889 s
[2019-11-27 21:33:28,130] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:33:28,130] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.01 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.986234 s
[2019-11-27 21:33:33,160] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-11-27 21:33:33,160] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.01 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.986669 s
```

Our logs are now too noisy to be useful. **How can we disable these**? Changing the log level to something like `logging.WARN` is not an option because we have lots of actually useful information at the `INFO` level.

EDIT: I'm using Airflow 1.10.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to disable it. I have created a [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6716) that changes the log level to DEBUG. Unfortunately, this won't be available until the next release (**1.10.7**).

The short-time solution would to manually apply the change in the [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6716) to your Airflow installation.