# Airflow heartbeat warning log cause ssh connection dropped

Tags: python-3.x, sftp, airflow, paramiko

I've run an airflow pod in Docker-desktop k8s environment on my macos.

One airflow task is aim to download a large size(**670MB**) gzip file from a remote sftp server.I use Python paramiko to create ssh connection then use its method to download the needed gzip files.

Actually my other airflow download tasks(file size not great than 30MB) could be executed successfully and gzip file could be downloaded entirely.

Below is the error airflow log, in it there are many `Time since last heartbeat(0.06 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.938538 s` warning logs which are really annoying and probably it's the root cause that caused `ssh connection dropped error`.

Use `airflow list_dags -r` shows below information about this dag

```
DagBag loading stats for /usr/local/airflow/dags
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of DAGs: 1
Total task number: 42
DagBag parsing time: 0.217942
------------------------------------+----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------
file                                | duration | dag_num | task_num | dags
------------------------------------+----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------
/downloader-dags.py                 | 0.217942 |       1 |       42 | ['file-downloader']
------------------------------------+----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------
```

See, from "2020-01-10 03:08:33,280" to "2020-01-10 03:29:38,638" nearly 22 minutes was wasted on airflow heartbeat check, during that time the file was only downloaded 8MB, a samll portion of the entire file(**670MB**).

Airflow Version : 1.10.6
Python: 3.7.6
Paramiko: 2.7.1
Kubenetes Version: v1.14.6
Docker desktop Version: 2.1.0.3

I've viewed this article [Airflow - Disable heartbeat logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142508/airflow-disable-heartbeat-logs) .I can't change `self.log.warning` to `self.log.debug` because of the airflow image owner is not me.

Could anyone help to solve this problem? any ideas about airflow heartbeat would be apprieciate thanks in advance.

```
[2020-01-10 03:08:27,906] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-10 03:08:27,906] {transport.py:1819} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client Twisted)
[2020-01-10 03:08:28,182] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-10 03:08:28,182] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.07 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.928218 s
[2020-01-10 03:08:29,824] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-10 03:08:29,824] {transport.py:1819} INFO - Authentication (password) successful!
[2020-01-10 03:08:29,996] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-10 03:08:29,995] {sftp.py:158} INFO - [chan 0] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
[2020-01-10 03:08:30,839] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - ftpclient.py sftp_get filename_fullpath: <class 'str'> /var/data/k8s/download/202001/daily_check.csv.gz
[2020-01-10 03:08:33,280] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-10 03:08:33,279] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.06 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.938538 s
......
[2020-01-10 03:29:38,638] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-10 03:29:38,637] {local_task_job.py:124} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.07 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.927038 s
[2020-01-10 03:29:41,907] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - 2020-01-10 03:29:41,906 - 10 -    ERROR -  184 - sftp_get:sftp_get downloader.csv.gz error:sftp_get filename_fullpath /var/data/k8s/download/202001/daily_check.csv.gz error:<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException'>:Server connection dropped:
[2020-01-10 03:29:41,918] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-10 03:29:41,906] {ftpclient.py:184} ERROR - sftp_get:sftp_get downloader.csv.gz error:sftp_get filename_fullpath /var/data/k8s/download/202001/daily_check.csv.gz error:<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException'>:Server connection dropped:
[2020-01-10 03:29:41,921] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - --- Logging error ---
[2020-01-10 03:29:41,911] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - 2020-01-10 03:29:41,906 - 10 -    ERROR -  184 - sftp_get:sftp_get downloader.csv.gz error:sftp_get filename_fullpath /var/data/k8s/download/202001/daily_check.csv.gz error:<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException'>:Server connection dropped:
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 538, in _prefetch_thread
    self, CMD_READ, self.handle, long(offset), int(length)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 837, in _async_request
    self._send_packet(t, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 198, in _send_packet
    self._write_all(out)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 164, in _write_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError
```

Comment: Actually my other airflow download tasks with small size file could be executed successfully, and gzip file could be downloaded entirely. Probably there are too many warning logs that cause Python paramiko ssh connection break.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342350/why-is-paramiko-raising-eoferror-when-the-sftp-object-is-stored-in-a-dictionar.  luckily i've read about this, @mokrates his point sound reasonable.

Comment: problem solved, it is due to paramiko download large file error.https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/926